# Hash_hmac equivalent in Node.js

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, amazon-s3, sign

I have code that is working in my PHP app.  In the PHP I sign the url with the following code:

```
private static function __getHash($string)
{
    return hash_hmac('sha1', $string, self::$__secretKey, true);    
}
```

I am attempting to sign the URL in the same way in a Node.js application.  This is what I'm trying:

```
S3.prototype.getHash = function(string){
    var key = this.secret_key; 
    var hmac = crypto.createHash('sha1', key);
    hmac.update(string); 
    return hmac.digest('binary'); 
};
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

Do these pieces of code do the same thing? Am I missing something?

Comment: Compare the outputs of the two hashes to see if they do the same thing.

Comment: For a start the `crypto.createHash` method in Node doesn't take a key because it calculates a hash not an HMAC.

Comment: @Chris, so theoretically, changing it to `createHmac` would fix that issue?

Comment: @Brody, I'm trying to, however I'm using Eclipse for the PHP and netBeans for the node and while netbeans has no problem displaying the output, Eclipse is not a fan of all the special characters

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The primary problem here is that you are using `createHash` which creates a hash, rather than `createHmac` which creates an HMAC.

Change `createHash` to `createHmac` and you should find it produces the same result.

This is the output you should expect:

```
chris /tmp/hmac $ cat node.js 
var crypto = require('crypto');
var key = 'abcd';
var data = 'wxyz';

function getHash(string){
    var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', key);
    hmac.update(string); 
    return hmac.digest('binary'); 
};

process.stdout.write(getHash(data));

chris /tmp/hmac $ cat php.php 
<?php
$key = "abcd";
$data = "wxyz";
function __getHash($string)
{
    global $key;
    return hash_hmac('sha1', $string, $key, true); 
}

echo utf8_encode(__getHash($data));

chris /tmp/hmac $ node node.js | base64
WsOKw4xgw4jDlFHDl3jDuEPDuCfCmsOFwoDCrsK/w6ka
chris /tmp/hmac $ php php.php | base64
WsOKw4xgw4jDlFHDl3jDuEPDuCfCmsOFwoDCrsK/w6ka
```

Comment: I'm still getting that the Signature does not match. Any idea why?

Comment: Well how are you comparing the binary data? If you compare them as strings you will need to make sure the encoding is correct. I've attached the output I get. Note I've converted the PHP output from latin-1 to UTF-8 and base64 encoded both outputs for easy comparison.

Comment: Sara: hash_hmac produces a hex digest by default

Answer (score 20):

This answer from Chris is good if you are porting `hash_hmac` with the last parameter being `true`. In this case, binary is produced, as is the case with Chris's javascript.

To add to that, this example:

```
 $sign = hash_hmac('sha512', $post_data, $secret);
```

Would be ported with a function like so in nodejs:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");

function signHmacSha512(key, str) {
  let hmac = crypto.createHmac("sha512", key);
  let signed = hmac.update(Buffer.from(str, 'utf-8')).digest("hex");
  return signed
}
```

The difference here being that when you leave off the last argument to hash_hmac (or set it to something not `true`), it behaves as defined in the PHP [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php):

> When set to TRUE, outputs raw binary data. FALSE outputs lowercase hexits.

In order to do this with node.js we use `digest('hex')` as you can see in the snippet.